# How install Eclipse from .tar.gz file?

Tags: installation, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I have downloaded eclipse-jee-juno-linux-gtk.tar.gz file, but i don't know how install it.

Comment: Have you tried installing Eclipse from the "Ubuntu Software Center?"

Comment: yes but the eclipse is not for web development.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is easy, just extract it.
You can do right click extract here or in the terminal

> tar -zxvf eclipse-jee-juno-linux-gtk.tar.gz

You will see the eclipse file in the folder double click it and that is all.

You can also use a normal GUI for this as well, So in most cases its a simple as right clicking on the file and selecting "Extract" or similar..

But as a further note, You generally do not want to have your applications sitting in your user directory/desktop/downloads... You shold move the extracted folder depending on your distro and then link via a normal menu icon/entry.

Else one day you might decide to empty your downloads folder and delete your installation/custom settings... and possibly projects for some who dont pay attention to folder/locations.

Answer (score 5):

Just decompress the downloaded file in the folder you want (can be **/opt/eclipse**)

To decompress it, you can do it via command line:

```
tar -zxvf eclipse-jee-juno-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

Or from your folder

```
Right click on the file / extract here / move it where you want to install it
```

Then, you can add a shortcut to your desktop or add it to your Applications' menu doing:

```
Right click in Applications/Edit Menus
Go to your prefered section (usually programming)
New Item / Browse to /opt/eclipse/eclipse (if you installed it there)
```

Good luck!